# PHP: to establish as first element of an array the element you need to

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with academic years:

```
$arrayAcademicYears = array( 
           array("8889", "1988-1989"),
           array("8990", "1989-1990"),
           array("9091", "1990-1991"),
           array("0405", "2004-2005"),
           array("1112", "2011-2012"),
           array("1213", "2012-2013")
         );
         foreach($arrayAcademicYears as $k => $v) {
             echo "KEY: ";
             echo $v[0];
             echo " -> VALUE: ";
             echo $v[1];
             echo "<br>";
         }
```

This prints:

```
KEY: 8889 -> VALUE: 1988-1989
KEY: 8990 -> VALUE: 1989-1990
KEY: 9091 -> VALUE: 1990-1991
KEY: 0405 -> VALUE: 2004-2005
KEY: 1112 -> VALUE: 2011-2012
KEY: 1213 -> VALUE: 2012-2013
```

Then I have the current academic year in a variable like this:

```
$currentAcademicYear="1112";
```

How can I change the code to print:

```
KEY: 1112 -> VALUE: 2011-2012
KEY: 1213 -> VALUE: 2012-2013
KEY: 0405 -> VALUE: 2004-2005
KEY: 9091 -> VALUE: 1990-1991
KEY: 8990 -> VALUE: 1989-1990
KEY: 8889 -> VALUE: 1988-1989
```

Please note that this is just an example, I’m not asking for a solution to any kind of academic course exercise. Just a self taught PHP learner here.

Thanks a lot! (.. for helping me becoming  a better PHP programmer :))

Comment: So what you are looking for is to print the current academic year first?

Comment: ..or are you looking to reverse the array?

Comment: What is the logic of your output?

Comment: Doing the reverse and then placing the current academic year on top of all elemnts. How can I do that? Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will reverse your array, displaying the newest first:

```
$arrayAcademicYears = array_reverse($arrayAcademicYears);
```

Place it just above:

```
foreach($arrayAcademicYears as $k => $v) {
```

Array_reverse will for some reason change the key's on all your items to 0 increment, except for the 04-05 year. Use the following function which is updated and will achieve the correct sorting.

```
    function array_mtf(&$arr, $keytom, $reverse = false){
        $tmp = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            if($key == $keytom){
                $tmp[$key] = $value;
                unset($arr[$key]);
            }
        }

                    if($reverse)
            arsort($arr);

        $arr = $tmp + $arr;
    }
```

Usage would be as:

```
array_mtf($array_to_sort, $key_to_move_first, true);
```

So add the function block to your code, and then replace:

```
$arrayAcademicYears = array_reverse($arrayAcademicYears);
```

With

```
array_mtf($arrayAcademicYears, $currentAcademicYear);
```

The resulting array would look like:

```
Array
(
[1112] => 2011-2012
[1213] => 2012-2013
[0405] => 2004-2005
[9091] => 1990-1991
[8990] => 1989-1990
[8889] => 1988-1989
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I need the currentAcademicYear 1112 above 1213. How can I add it now to the top of the elements?

Comment: Updated answer with a new approach and function to achieve your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to learn, i recomend you to use a easier logic, using only one array, like this:

```
// Creating an array with associative keys
$arrayAcademicYears = array( 
    "8889" => "1988-1989",
    "8990" => "1989-1990",
    "9091" => "1990-1991",
    "0405" => "2004-2005",
    "1112" => "2011-2012",
    "1213" => "2012-2013"
    );

// Defining the current year
$currentAcademicYear = "1112";

// Printing the key and content of the current year
echo "KEY: " . $currentAcademicYear . " -> VALUE: " . $arrayAcademicYears[$currentAcademicYear] . "<br />";

// Removing from array the key printed above
unset($arrayAcademicYears[$currentAcademicYear]);

// Getting a reverse array, preserving the keys using the "true" parameter
$arrayAcademicYears = array_reverse($arrayAcademicYears, true);

// Now printing the other keys and its contents, following your logic
foreach($arrayAcademicYears as $key => $value)
    echo "KEY: " . $key . " -> VALUE: " . $value . "<br />";
```

Hope it can help you!